# Create favorite listview with shared preferences

Tags: android, mysql, database, listview, sharedpreferences

I have a listview of ringtones .. I feed the list via mysql database.. (such as song names,song urls ...). I dynamically add products(ringtones) in my listview by adding new item in my database, so none of this data are inside my app except row icons.

***This is the view***

[image: This is the view]

As you can see I have a bookmark border icon that when user clicks on it, it will turn into selected...This is how it works :

```
    @Override
    public void favOnClick(int position) {
       Product product = productList.get(position);
        if (product.faved) {
            sharedPreference.addFavorite(activity,product);
            product.setFavId(R.mipmap.bookmarked);
            product.faved=false;
        }else {
            sharedPreference.removeFavorite(activity,product);
            product.setFavId(R.mipmap.bookmark_border);
            product.faved = true;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
        };
```

but nothing will happen in my "FAVORITES" tab .. Even the state of bookmark icon when it is selected will not be saved..

**Custom Adapter**

```
    public class FunDapter<T> extends BaseAdapter {

       public interface PlayPauseClick {
             void favOnClick(int position);
            }


       private PlayPauseClick callback;
       public void setPlayPauseClickListener(PlayPauseClick listener) {
            this.callback = listener;
        }


    protected List<T> mDataItems;
    protected List<T> mOrigDataItems;
    protected final Context mContext;
    private final int mLayoutResource;
    private final BindDictionary<T> mBindDictionary;



    public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                     BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
      this(context, dataItems, layoutResource, null, dictionary);
    }


    public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                     LongExtractor<T> idExtractor, BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDataItems = dataItems;
        this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
        this.mLayoutResource = layoutResource;
        this.mBindDictionary = dictionary;
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
    }



    public void updateData(List<T> dataItems) {
        this.mDataItems = dataItems;
        this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mDataItems == null || mBindDictionary == null) return 0;

        return mDataItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public T getItem(int position) {
        return mDataItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if(idExtractor == null) return position;
        else return idExtractor.getLongValue(getItem(position), position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        final GenericViewHolder holder;
        if (null == v) {
            LayoutInflater vi =
                    (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(mLayoutResource, null);
            holder = new GenericViewHolder();
            holder.root = v;


            //init the sub views and put them in a holder instance
            FunDapterUtils.initViews(v, holder, mBindDictionary);
            v.setTag(holder);
            }else {
            holder = (GenericViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

        final T item = getItem(position);
        showData(item, holder, position);

        Product product = (Product) mDataItems.get(position);
        holder.favImage=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.favImage); 
        holder.favImage.setImageResource(product.getFavId());
        holder.favImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (callback != null) {
                      callback.favOnClick(position);
                    } 
            }
        }); 


        return v;
    }

}
```

**Product model class**

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("pid")
    public int pid;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("qty")
    public int qty;

    @SerializedName("price")
    public String description;

    @SerializedName("song_url")
    public String song_url;

    @SerializedName("date")
    public String date;


    public boolean paused = true;
    public boolean faved = true;

     private int favId;
    public int getFavId() {
        return favId;}
    public void setFavId(int favId) {
        this.favId = favId;} 
}
```

**SharedPreferences class**

```
   public class SharedPreference {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PRODUCT_APP";
    public static final String FAVORITES = "Product_Favorite";

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }

    // This four methods are used for maintaining favorites.
    public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<Product> favorites) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);
        editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addFavorite(Context context, Product product) {
        List<Product> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites == null)
            favorites = new ArrayList<Product>();
            favorites.add(product);
            saveFavorites(context, favorites);
    }

    public void removeFavorite(Context context, Product product) {
        ArrayList<Product> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites != null) {
            favorites.remove(product);
            saveFavorites(context, favorites);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Product> getFavorites(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        List<Product> favorites;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
            String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Product[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,Product[].class);
            favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
            favorites = new ArrayList<Product>(favorites);
        } else
            return null;

        return (ArrayList<Product>) favorites;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck here for a few days, Can you help me please !

This is my project link if you would like to look into it for further info

<s>http://symphonyrecords.ir/RingtoneApp.rar</s>

Comment: Is your favOnClick(int position) method triggered when a bookmark icon i pressed?

Comment: Yes , I forgot to add those here , I've edited my question

Comment: So the tone that's selected as favorite does get stored in SharedPreference ?

Comment: In my SharedPreferences class I have a saveFavorites method that will be called in addFavorite method .. And as you said I trigger the addFavorite when user clicks to select a row as favorite

Comment: Well i believe it's :listAdapter.get(position).setFavId(R.mipmap.bookmarked);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here (based on your project)

***First*** (*saving state of bookmark Imageview*)

In adapter create a method that checks whether a particular product exists in SharedPreferences

```
    public boolean checkFavoriteItem(Product checkProduct) {
    boolean check = false;
    List<Product> favorites = sharedPreference.getFavorites(null, mContext);
    if (favorites != null) {
        for (Product product : favorites) {
            if (product.equals(checkProduct)) {
                check = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return check;
}
```

Inside adapter check if a product exists in shared preferences then set **bookmarked** drawable and set a tag

```
if (checkFavoriteItem(product)) {
        holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bookmarked);
        holder.favoriteImg.setTag("bookmarked");
    } else {
        holder.favoriteImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bookmark_border);
        holder.favoriteImg.setTag("bookmark_border");
    }
```

Then inside favOnClick callback method

```
    @Override
    public boolean favOnClick(int position ,View v) {
        Product product = (Product) productList.get(position);
        ImageView button = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.favImage);
        String tag = button.getTag().toString();
        if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("bookmark_border")) {
            sharedPreference.addFavorite(activity,product);
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Added to Favorites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            button.setTag("bookmarked");
            button.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bookmarked);
        } else {
            sharedPreference.removeFavorite(activity,product);
            button.setTag("bookmark_border");
            button.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bookmark_border);
            Toast.makeText(activity,"Removed from Favorites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
        }
```

***Second*** (*get favorite product and pass it to "FAVORITE" Fragment*)

Inside getFavorite method add a String parameter
Then in your "FAVORITE" Fragment with processFinish(your AsyncResponse) call your getFavorite in order to get your Favorite product list then set your adapter :

```
Context mContext;
`mContext = getContext();`

@Override
public void  processFinish(String s) {
    productList = sharedPreference.getFavorites(s, mContext);

    BindDictionary<Product> dict = new BindDictionary<Product>();
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvName, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
            return product.name;
        }
    });


    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvDescription, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
            return product.description;

        }
    });


    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvQty, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
            return "" + product.qty;

        }
    });


    adapter = new FunDapter<>(getActivity(), productList, R.layout.d_layout_list_d, dict);
    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `favOnClick` method change the object in `FunDapter.mDataItems`.
So, Change the callback method:

```
    @Override
    public void favOnClick(int position) {
       Product product = adapter.get(position);
        if (product.faved) {
            sharedPreference.addFavorite(activity, product);
            product.setFavId(R.mipmap.bookmarked);
            product.faved=false;
        }else {
            sharedPreference.removeFavorite(activity, product);
            product.setFavId(R.mipmap.bookmark_border);
            product.faved = true;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
        };
```

Comment: I put a log on my sharedPreferences class,  in addFavorite method I loged "favorites" and convert it to string .. It gave me the product package name , This isn't right , is it ?

Comment: I mean it should give me the product specification rather than just the package name, right ?

Comment: You did not overwrite the `toString()` method

Answer (score 0):

**Check this, 99% working code**

> On click Fav Btn

```
List< RvModel > favorites_list = storageFavorites.loadFavourite();
            boolean exist = false;
            if (favorites_list == null) {
                favorites_list = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < favorites_list.size(); i++) {
                if (favorites_list.get(i).getId().equals(rvModelArrayList.get(position).getId())) {
                    exist = true;
                }
            }
            if (!exist) {
                ArrayList< RvModel > audios = new ArrayList< RvModel >(favorites_list);
                audios.add(rvModelArrayList.get(position));
                storageFavorites.storeImage(audios);
                holder.bookMarkBtn.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_full));
            } else {
                ArrayList< RvModel > new_favorites = new ArrayList< RvModel >();
                for (int i = 0; i < favorites_list.size(); i++) {
                    if (!favorites_list.get(i).getId().equals(rvModelArrayList.get(position).getId())) {
                        new_favorites.add(favorites_list.get(i));

                    }
                }
                if (favorites) {
                    Log.v("DOWNLOADED", "favorites==true");
                    rvModelArrayList.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //holder.ripple_view_wallpaper_item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                storageFavorites.storeImage(new_favorites);
                holder.bookMarkBtn.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bookmark));
            }
        }
```