# Saving listview data in SharedPreferences (Favorites list)

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter, android-preferences

I have a listview of ringtones .. I feed the list via mysql database.. (such as song names,song urls ...).
New row will be added to the list when I insert new column in my database, so none of this data are inside my app except row icons.

***This is the view***

[image: View]

As you can see I have a bookmark border icon that when user clicks on it, it will turn into selected...This is how it works :

```
    @Override
    public void favOnClick(int position) {
       Product product = productList.get(position);
        if (product.faved) {
            sharedPreference.addFavorite(activity,product);
            product.setFavId(R.mipmap.bookmarked);
            product.faved=false;
        }else {
            sharedPreference.removeFavorite(activity,product);
            product.setFavId(R.mipmap.bookmark_border);
            product.faved = true;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
        };
```

but nothing will happen in my "FAVORITES" tab .. Even the state of bookmark icon when it is selected will not be saved..

**Custom Adapter**

```
    public class FunDapter<T> extends BaseAdapter {

       public interface PlayPauseClick {
             void favOnClick(int position);
            }


       private PlayPauseClick callback;
       public void setPlayPauseClickListener(PlayPauseClick listener) {
            this.callback = listener;
        }


    protected List<T> mDataItems;
    protected List<T> mOrigDataItems;
    protected final Context mContext;
    private final int mLayoutResource;
    private final BindDictionary<T> mBindDictionary;



    public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                     BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
      this(context, dataItems, layoutResource, null, dictionary);
    }


    public FunDapter(Context context, List<T> dataItems, int layoutResource,
                     LongExtractor<T> idExtractor, BindDictionary<T> dictionary) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDataItems = dataItems;
        this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
        this.mLayoutResource = layoutResource;
        this.mBindDictionary = dictionary;
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference();
    }



    public void updateData(List<T> dataItems) {
        this.mDataItems = dataItems;
        this.mOrigDataItems = dataItems;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mDataItems == null || mBindDictionary == null) return 0;

        return mDataItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public T getItem(int position) {
        return mDataItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if(idExtractor == null) return position;
        else return idExtractor.getLongValue(getItem(position), position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        final GenericViewHolder holder;
        if (null == v) {
            LayoutInflater vi =
                    (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(mLayoutResource, null);
            holder = new GenericViewHolder();
            holder.root = v;


            //init the sub views and put them in a holder instance
            FunDapterUtils.initViews(v, holder, mBindDictionary);
            v.setTag(holder);
            }else {
            holder = (GenericViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }

        final T item = getItem(position);
        showData(item, holder, position);

        Product product = (Product) mDataItems.get(position);
        holder.favImage=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.favImage); 
        holder.favImage.setImageResource(product.getFavId());
        holder.favImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (callback != null) {
                      callback.favOnClick(position);
                    } 
            }
        }); 


        return v;
    }

}
```

**Product model class**

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Product implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("pid")
    public int pid;

    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;

    @SerializedName("qty")
    public int qty;

    @SerializedName("price")
    public String description;

    @SerializedName("song_url")
    public String song_url;

    @SerializedName("date")
    public String date;


    public boolean paused = true;
    public boolean faved = true;

     private int favId;
    public int getFavId() {
        return favId;}
    public void setFavId(int favId) {
        this.favId = favId;} 
}
```

**SharedPreferences class**

```
   public class SharedPreference {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PRODUCT_APP";
    public static final String FAVORITES = "Product_Favorite";

    public SharedPreference() {
        super();
    }

    // This four methods are used for maintaining favorites.
    public void saveFavorites(Context context, List<Product> favorites) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        Editor editor;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonFavorites = gson.toJson(favorites);
        editor.putString(FAVORITES, jsonFavorites);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void addFavorite(Context context, Product product) {
        List<Product> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites == null)
            favorites = new ArrayList<Product>();
            favorites.add(product);
            saveFavorites(context, favorites);
    }

    public void removeFavorite(Context context, Product product) {
        ArrayList<Product> favorites = getFavorites(context);
        if (favorites != null) {
            favorites.remove(product);
            saveFavorites(context, favorites);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Product> getFavorites(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        List<Product> favorites;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (settings.contains(FAVORITES)) {
            String jsonFavorites = settings.getString(FAVORITES, null);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Product[] favoriteItems = gson.fromJson(jsonFavorites,Product[].class);
            favorites = Arrays.asList(favoriteItems);
            favorites = new ArrayList<Product>(favorites);
        } else
            return null;

        return (ArrayList<Product>) favorites;
    }
}
```

I'm stuck here for a few days, Can you help me please !

Comment: Why you stock the favId ? You should just do this in your adapter : `if(product.faved){ holder.favImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bookmarked);} else { holder.favImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bookmark_border); }`

Comment: You are right, I had the same operation with play and pause button so I copy and pase it for fav Icon for now ,  I'll change this later .. but this will not solve my current problem

Comment: @BenjaminBihr I've started a bounty on my question from my primary account, I also included my project there , you can look into it if you got some free time, here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620480/create-favorite-listview-with-shared-preferences